# Как реализовать отдельное управление для каждого нового созданного счетчика?

Tags: javascript, dom

Есть простой счетчик и кнопки управления ним, **+** добавляет единицу, а **-** отнимает, так же при нажатии кнопки create создается новый счетчик.

Нужно чтобы каждый новый созданный счетчик управлялся отдельно, я пытался сделать делегирование но у меня не получилось, при создании нового счетчика и нажатии на **+** или **-** единица добавляется или отнимается в первом элементе. Что-то я упускаю!

*jsfiddle* - https://jsfiddle.net/ua52s0kq/

```
<button class = 'create'>Create</button>
<div id='container'>
  <div id='menu'>
    <div class = 'dayy'> 
      <button class='minus'>-</button>
      День <span class='value'>0</span>
      <button class='plus'>+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
const menu = document.querySelector('#menu');
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
const day = document.querySelector('.dayy');
const create = document.querySelector('.create');
const getMinus = document.querySelector('.minus');
const getPlus = document.querySelector('.plus');
const getValue = document.querySelector('.value');

let currentValue = 0;

container.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('plus')) {
    currentValue++;
    getValue.innerHTML = currentValue;
  }
});

container.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('minus')) {
    if (currentValue > 0) {
      currentValue--;
      getValue.innerHTML = currentValue;
    }
  }
});

create.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.setAttribute('class', 'dayy');
  elem.innerHTML = '<button class='minus'>-</button> День <span class='value'>0</span> <button class="plus">+</button>';
  menu.append (elem);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что независимо от созданных элементов, у вас `currentValue` всегда хранит число для первого элемента, и `getValue` - также ссылается на первый элемент.

Вообще говоря, принято использовать HTML для отображения данных, а не их хранения. Но если вы и так предоставляете способ изменения чисел, не случится ничего страшного, если использовать textContent для получения текущего числа:

```js
const _first = (str, root) => (root || document).querySelector(str);

_first("#container").addEventListener('click', function({target}) {
  if (target.matches(".plus")) {
    let elem = _first(".value", target.closest(".dayy"));
    // Первый .value внутри ближайшего .dayy (идет как параметр `root`)
    elem.textContent = Number(elem.textContent) + 1;
    
    return;
  }
  
  if (target.matches(".minus")) {    
    let elem = _first(".value", target.closest(".dayy"));
    elem.textContent = Math.max(0, elem.textContent - 1);
    
    return;
  }
});

_first(".create").addEventListener('click', function() {
  _first("#menu").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", `
    <div class="dayy">
      <button class="minus">-</button>
      День <span class="value">0</span>
      <button class="plus">+</button>
    </div>
  `);
  // `Обратные` кавычки допускают многострочную запись.
  // При этом, между элементами появляются пробелы: иногда это может помешать.
});
```

```html
<button class = "create">Create</button>
<div id="container">
  <div id="menu">
    <div class = "dayy"> 
      <button class="minus">-</button>
      День <span class="value">0</span>
      <button class="plus">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если бы очень хотелось хранить число-счетчик в переменной, можно было бы завести массив:

```js
const _first = (str, root) => (root || document).querySelector(str);
const _all = (str) => document.querySelectorAll(str);

let counters = [0];

_first("#container").addEventListener('click', function({target}) {
  let day = target.closest(".dayy");
  if (!day) return;

  let index = [..._all(".dayy")].indexOf(day);
  // номер текущего элемента среди всех остальных (google → spread оператор)
  
  let diff = target.matches(".plus") ? 1 : target.matches(".minus") ? -1 : 0;
  // +1, -1 или 0 — смотря куда кликнули.

  _first(".value", day).textContent = Math.max(0, counters[index] += diff);
   // counters[index] += diff значение в массиве в соответствующей позиции
   // меняется на +1 / -1 / 0, возвращается результат присваивания,
   // который попадает в textContent
});

_first(".create").addEventListener('click', function() {
  _first("#menu").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", `
    <div class="dayy">
      <button class="minus">-</button>
      День <span class="value">0</span>
      <button class="plus">+</button>
    </div>
  `);
  
  counters.push(0);
  // При создании каждого нового элемента, для него добавляется и счетчик
  // Номер счетчика в массиве - будет соответствовать
  // номеру HTML-элемента среди остальных таких же.
});
```

```html
<button class = "create">Create</button>
<div id="container">
  <div id="menu">
    <div class = "dayy"> 
      <button class="minus">-</button>
      День <span class="value">0</span>
      <button class="plus">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.s. Конечно же, в реальном коде не стал бы "умничать", а записал бы через обычные if-else.

P.p.s. Можете посмотреть, что такое функции-конструкторы / замыкание, попробовать реализовать через них)

Comment: Добавил вариант "Используя HTML для отображения данных"

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1):

Используя HTML для отображения данных:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> counters </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script>
"use strict"

const { useEffect, useState }  = React
const e = React.createElement

const App = () => {
    const [ items, setItems ] = useState([0])
    const changeValue = (cPos,delta) => setItems(cItems=>cItems.map((value,pos) => (
        pos !== cPos ? value : Math.max(0, value+delta)
    )))
    const addCounter = () => setItems(cItems=>[...cItems,0])
    return [
        e("button", { key: "create", className: "create", onClick: ev => addCounter() }, "Create"),
        e("div", { key: "container", className: "container" },
            e("div", { className: "menu" },
                items.map((value,pos) =>(
                    e("div", { key: pos, className: "dayy" },
                        e("button", { key: "m", className: "minus", onClick: ev=>changeValue(pos,-1) }, "-"),
                        " День ", e("span", { key: "v", className: "value" }, value),
                        e("button", { key: "p", className: "plus", onClick: ev=>changeValue(pos,+1) }, "+"),
                    )
                ))
            )
        )
    ]
}

ReactDOM.render(e(App), document.querySelector('.container'))

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: + Для любителей HTML-синтаксиса есть jsx